# How can I get the weekday from an users input date?

Tags: javascript, html

```js
function date() {
            var input = document.getElementById("input");

        }
```

```html
<form>
    <input type="date" placeholder="dd:mm:yy" id="input"/>
    <input type="button" value="weekday" onclick="date()"/>
</form>
    <p id="output">

    </p>
```

How can I get the Weekday? I have tried many things and searched on google but haven't found anything.
Thanks for help!

Comment: Read : [What should I do when someone answers my question?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers)

Answer (score 3):

Code which takes inputs in the format `mm/dd/yyyy` :

```html
<script>
  function day_of_week() {
    var weekday = ["Sunday", "Monday", "Tuesday", "Wednesday", "Thursday", "Friday", "Saturday"];

    var d = document.getElementById('date_input').valueAsDate;
    var n = d.getUTCDay()
    document.getElementById("output").innerHTML = weekday[n];
  }

</script>

<form>
  <input type="date" placeholder="dd:mm:yy" id="date_input" />
  <input type="button" value="Get Weekday" onclick="day_of_week()" />
</form>
<p id="output">

</p>
```

Comment: Downvoted because the weekday you get from this may be off by up to one day.

Comment: @tvanc Why would it be so?

Comment: The date shown in the field is UTC, whereas the value returned by `valueAsDate` is in your browser's timezone. My timzeone is `GMT-0700`. If I select Monday, `2022-04-11`, this code tells me I picked Sunday.

Comment: @tvanc ok, could you post an answer with the right code or update this for future ref.

Comment: Yes. Fixed it by using `getUTCDay()`, not `getDay()`.

Answer (score 0):

You're getting the element, you just need to grab the value.

```
var weekdays = ["Sunday", "Monday", "Tuesday", "Wednesday", "Thursday", "Friday", "Saturday"];

function date() {
  var input = document.getElementById("input");
  var date = new Date(input.value);
  var weekday = date.getDay();

  var output = document.getElementById("output");
  output.text = weekdays[weekday];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like this:

```js
function date() {
  var input = document.getElementById("input").value;
  var date = new Date(input).getUTCDay();
  
  var weekday = ['Sunday', 'Monday', 'Tuesday', 'Wednesday', 'Thursday', 'Friday', 'Saturday', 'Sunday'];
  
  document.getElementById('output').textContent = weekday[date];
}
```

```html
<form>
  <input type="date" placeholder="dd:mm:yy" id="input" />
  <input type="button" value="weekday" onclick="date()" />
</form>
<p id="output">

</p>
```

Answer (score 0):

Whenever you use the HTML 5 input type = "date" format for date picker, you can directly get the value in date format,so no need to convert that to date format , also to set the value in your p tag with id="output" you can use the textContent method as shown below:

```
<form>
  <input type="date" placeholder="dd:mm:yy" id="selectedDate" />
  <input type="button" value="weekday" onclick="date()" />
</form>
<p id="output"></p>

function date() {
  var inputDate = document.getElementById("selectedDate").valueAsDate;
  var day = inputDate.getDay();
  var days = ["Sunday", "Monday", "Tuesday", "Wednesday", "Thursday", "Friday", "Saturday"];
  document.getElementById('output').textContent = (days[day]);
}
```

The getDay() function for date, gives you the number of the weekday of a given date,which is used as index position in weekdays names array.